# ¿Cómo crear una instancia en SYBASE?

Tags: sybase

soy nuevo en SYBASE, quisiera saber como se crea un instancia en SYBASE, he buscado información al respecto pero no encuentro, si alguien podría darme alguna información referente a se lo agradecería mucho.

Answer (score 0):

En Sybase el concepto de instancia es el nombre que se le da al motor de base de datos durante la instalación.  Sobre la instancia se crean las bases de datos de usuario.   En una maquina pueden existir varios nombres de instancia con sus respectivas bases de datos, todo dependiendo del uso adecuado de recursos (memoria, cpu y disco).

Con el programa **sqlsrvbuildres** se pueden crear instancias basadas en un archivo de recursos como por ejemplo:

sybinit.release_directory: USE_DEFAULT

sybinit.product: sqlsrv

**sqlsrv.server_name: *NOMBRE INSTANCIA***

sqlsrv.new_config: yes

sqlsrv.do_add_server: yes

sqlsrv.network_protocol_list: tcp

sqlsrv.network_hostname_list: PUT_YOUR_HOSTNAME_HERE

sqlsrv.network_port_list: PUT_YOUR_PORT_NUMBER_HERE

sqlsrv.application_type: USE_DEFAULT

sqlsrv.server_page_size: USE_DEFAULT

Saludos,

(c) White